# Implementation of Day/Calendar view using ViewPager : Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-viewpager2

I have an Android app meant to be used for tracking gym workouts.
I save the workouts using Room based on the day's timestamp.

I want to firstly display the current day, then to be able to swipe in the past and feature
[image]

I used a viewpager and 2 approaches:

- First was to compute the dates for today + and - one month and feed the list into the viewpager adapter, this end up loading too many fragments at once
- The second one was to only have a list of 3 fragments in the adapter (selected date +/- one day) then replacing the fragments on user swipe, this only worked for swiping into future, by adding one item to the end of the list, and deleting the first one.

Are there any other suggestions or solutions for my issue ?
Thank you!